# How should questions involving pre-release or test kernel versions be regarded?

Tags: discussion

The [FAQ](https://askubuntu.com/faq) indicates that "issues with the next version of Ubuntu" aren't on topic. Should or should not a similar policy be adopted towards questions about pre-release and test kernels?

For example, 12.10 currently has `3.5.0-25-generic` but [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/260589/25656) is (partly) about "How to install kernel 3.8 from source on Ubuntu 12.10?"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Questions about Ubuntu+1 tend to be off topic because they're speculative or relevant for only a microsecond until a bug is fixed.

I don't think there'd be the same issue with a question about updating to an unsupported version of a package... Fact is we already have hundreds of such questions and they usually get satisfactory answers.

So no, I think they're on topic.

To be clear, I'm talking about installation. If people have problems with the pre-release software, that's probably a slightly different issue.

Answer (score 1):

A question about "how to install" a custom kernel is on topic. But the question regarding issues with these unsupported kernels are off-topic.

Some programs or drivers may be incompatible with brand new kernels. These type of questions give no value, because in most cases when a specific kernel is officially supported by some new Ubuntu release, most of the issues will be resolved.

It is the same as support of unreleased Ubuntu versions.

Otherwise there will be a lot of questions about issues with each and every new kernel. It can be asked at Unix & Linux.